# Password recovery in asp.net c# web forms application works on localhost but not on Godaddy server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net c# web forms application that utilizes the password recovery control.  The password recovery sends an email with a new password when running it on my localhost.  But when I try it from my Godaddy server it times-out.

Here's what I have:

Basic password recovery control:

```
<asp:PasswordRecovery ID="PasswordRecovery1" runat="server"></asp:PasswordRecovery>
```

web.config file has:

```
<mailSettings>
  <smtp from="me@gmail.com">
    <network host="smtp.gmail.com" password="mypwd" port="587"
      userName="me@gmail.com" enableSsl="true" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

What do I need to do in order to get this working on GoDaddy?

Comment: @uer1916528 here you are using `smtp.gmail` ,you are not using the godady right ? so you asking you want to send email through godaddy , or you want to make it work thorough gmail only but when hosted in godady ?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use Godaddy (secureserver) email instead of Gmail.  To get this to work simply change the web.config file to:

```
<mailSettings
    <network host="relay-hosting.secureserver.net" />
</mailSettings>
```